# Implicitly convert from std::string to eastl::string

Tags: c++, string, stl

I was using string class from stl `std::string` now I want to replace everything with [eastl](https://github.com/paulhodge/EASTL). So the easy question:

```
eastl::string obj = std::string("test");
```

> error: conversion from ‘the::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to
>   non-scalar type ‘eastl::string {aka eastl::basic_string}’
>   requested

Is it possible to automate conversion between this types?

Comment: Try eastl::string str(std::string("test").cstr());

Comment: Is it a typo that you are not initializing `std::string` to anything ?

Comment: @Mahesh Yes, sorry. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Well, just replace **everything**. You did *not* replace everything. Why do you still have a `std::string` in your code? EASTL is meant as a drop-in replacement for the standard library, not as a complement.

Comment: for my curiosity - why do you want to do this

Comment: STL does not have a string class. It has iterators, algorithms, containers, and function objects. The question is about the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: @pm100 as a temporary step to replace everything into new strings. Can't change all the code at once.

Comment: i mean - why dont you want to keep using the standard library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not if `eastl::string` does not define a copy constructor/assignment operator for `std::string`.

The simplest way to go from a `std::string` to an `eastl::string` would be to use the `.c_str()` method to get a pointer to the `std::string`'s internal char array

```
std::string ss("hello");
eastl::string es = ss.c_str();
```

You can add your own if you want to modify the library. **Although that is probably a bad idea**

simple example:

```
class MyString {
    private:
        char *str;
    public:
        MyString(const std::string &s) {
            str = new char[s.length() + 1]; /* allocate */
            strcpy(this->str, s.c_str());   /* copy */
        }
        ~MyString() {
            delete [] str;
        }
};
```

Then you can create a new MyString with:

```
MyString ms = std::string("hello");
```

Comment: While there is no direct support for the conversion, it does have all of the building blocks. There is no need to fork and modify EASTL to get this to work. MOreover, suggesting a fork of a professional grade library to someone that was not able to identify what constructor is probably a suggestion for pain and despair down the road.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas It's no problem for me to write this. I've also added conversion operator to const char* for this type and everything works okay. The question was more like: how to do this without touching the original sources :) Something like ostream global operator.

Comment: @Ockonal: The problem with forking a library is that any change upstream would have to be merged to your codebase. There are solutions that don't involve modifying the code in the library, and that should be preferred. Also note that the lack of conversion to `const char*` in the standard library is a conscious design decision. When considering conversions, remember: *there be dragons*

Comment: @Ockonal forking the library is discouraged for the reasons mentioned unless you could actually have your changes merged into the library after making them.

Answer (score 2):

```
eastl::string obj1 = "test";             // works out of the box
eastl::string obj2 = std_string.c_str(); // equivalent to above
eastl::string obj3(&std_string[0],       // another option
                   &std_string[0]+std_string.size());
```

Comment: mmm. Is the obvious 'eastl::string(std_string.begin(), std_string.end())` not an option?

Comment: @sehe: It seems it is not, although I did not pay much attention, but it seems that the `eastl::basic_string` does not have templated constructors.

Answer (score 0):

These classes are not compatible. eastl::string has no constructor with std::string argument. So you should use something like this:
srd::string stlstr = "test";
eastl::string eastlstr= strlstr.c_str();